# Creating Azure VirtualMachineExtension failure

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sdk-python

I have a Windows Machine that I want to add VM extension using the azure python SDK , I send the following request

```
{'location': 'westus', 
'tags': None, 
'publisher': 'Microsoft.Compute', 
'virtual_machine_extension_type': 'CustomScriptExtension', 
'type_handler_version': '1.4', 
'settings': '{
"file_uris": ["https://mysite.azurescripts.net/ps_enable_winrm_http.ps1"],
 "command_to_execute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file ps_enable_winrm_http.ps1"}'
}
```

but what happens is that it gives the following exception

```
configure virtual_machine '946b4246-a604-4b01-9e6a-09ed64a93bdb' failed with this error : 
VM has reported a failure when processing extension '13da0dc5-09c0-4e56-a35d-fdbc42432e11'.
Error message: "Invalid handler configuration. Exiting. 
Error Message: Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. "

More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot
```

adding a simple code snippet that I use

```
vm_extension_name = "{0}".format(uuid4())
vm_extension_params = {
    'location': location_val,
    'tags': tags_val,
    'publisher': 'Microsoft.Compute',
    'virtual_machine_extension_type': 'CustomScriptExtension',
    'type_handler_version': type_handler_version,
    'auto_upgrade_minor_version': True,
    'settings': json.dumps({
        'fileUris': file_uris,
        'commandToExecute': command_to_execute
     })
}
logger.info("sending {0}".format(vm_extension_params))
```

any ideas , should I send something differently or am I missing something from the above request that cause the issue

thanks for the help in advance

Regards,

Comment: Can you change the type_handler_version': to 1.9 or 1.10?

Comment: Could you please check if the file URL is public?

Comment: @NancyXiong I tried many values of type handler , I saw on one of github issues , that change it to 1.8 or 1.5 and I tried those but same issue , so I went of something that used to work with rest api 1.4

Comment: @JimXu , I can tell with 100% that the file is there , since I take it from github , but I changed the site name for the sake of the example and illustration of the problem

Comment: just a small note this method was working OK before switching to use the SDK instead of rest call using requests module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use python sdk to install custom script extension, we should create Object `VirtualMachineExtension`. Its parameter `settings` should be `Object`. But you define it as `str`. Please update it with removing `''`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_12_01.models.virtualmachineextension?view=azure-python)

For example

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
AZURE_TENANT_ID= ''
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=''
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET='' 
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=''

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=AZURE_CLIENT_ID,secret=AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,tenant=AZURE_TENANT_ID)
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

resource_group_name='stan'
vm_name='win2016'
params_create = {
        'location':'CentralUS',
        'tags': None,
        'publisher': 'Microsoft.Compute',
        'virtual_machine_extension_type': 'CustomScriptExtension',
        'type_handler_version': '1.4',
        'settings':
        {
            'fileUris': ['https://***/test/test.ps1'],
            'commandToExecute': 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File test.ps1'
        }
 }

ext_poller = compute_client.virtual_machine_extensions.create_or_update(
    resource_group_name,
    vm_name,
    'test',
    params_create,
)
ext = ext_poller.result()
print(ext)
```

[image]

Comment: am not adding it as str [ it is json.dumps for the values , it would appear so because I am printing it ]

Comment: any ideas , so what you wrote above is similar to what I use already

Comment: I even see wrong params in your snippet Tag instead of tags https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.models.virtualmachineextension?view=azure-python

Comment: @AhMaDAbUIeSa According to my test, we cannot use the `json.dumps` to define settings. Once we do that, we can get the error you said : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsbRD.png. We need to define the settings like `'settings': 
        {
            'fileUris': file_uris,
            'commandToExecute':command_to_execute 
        }` :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YR1F.png

Comment: I will try that , and update you , that is good , I thought since the data type is object , I had to assign it that

Comment: tried and looks like yeah the exception went away , thanks @jim-xu